# How to colect data from dynamicaly created php table

Tags: php, mysql, web, html

I'm new in php and webdevelop so i have simple problem.

**Background of the story:**
I have form in PHP (table) where I keep gifts list.
There are 3 column: number, gift description and info who booked gift (or if no one booked target gift, there is input text file that allow to book gift).
At the end of table there will be place to propose your own gift idea.

```
<?php
    db_connect();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT GIFTS_ID, USER_DESCR, GIFT_DESCR FROM GIFTS");
    $array = array();
    while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $array[] = $row_user;
    $howManyRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    db_close();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    table id="PersonList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lp </th>
            <th>Gift Description </th>
            <th>Reservation </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($array as $gifts) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                echo    '<td class="number">' . "{$gifts['GIFTS_ID']}" . '</td>';
                echo    '<td class="description">' . "{$gifts['GIFT_DESCR']}" . '</td>';
                echo    '<td class="reservation">' . selectWhatToDisplay("{$gifts['USER_DESCR']}") . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</form> 

<?php
function selectWhatToDisplay($USER_DESCR) {
    if ($USER_DESCR == 'N') 
    {
        return '<input type="text" name="reserv_data[]">';
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $USER_DESCR;
    }      
}
?>
```

As u see rows are created dynamicaly when user open website.

**PROBLEM:**
I want allow user to book more than one gift in single "Send" operation but I dont know how to collect data from dynamic created table:  what rows was the target and what was data in single text field.

---EDITED---
My problem is that now i have multiple id named "reserv_data[]" as input field. Normal way to reach this kind of field is $_POST['name_of_field']. Now I dont know how to get (ie 5'th input file - 5'th means from 5'th row of table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to select all the input fields and then check which of those have a value that's long enough(longer than 0 i guess).

Once you have the array of inputs you can organize them into a nice ajax call to the server.

All your inputs can be structed like this :

`<input data-bookID="BOOK_ID" type="text">`

This way you have all the information you need, the BOOK_ID can be generated dynamically when you construct the table.

I hope i understood your question properly :P

Comment: Hmm...maby I asked wrong question.
I dont want use JS. I think that it can be solved only in PHP.

My problem is that now i have multiple id named "reserv_data[]" as input field.
Normal way to reach this kind of field is $_POST['name_of_field'].
Now I dont know how to get (ie 5'th input file - 5'th means from 5'th row of table).

Comment: reserv_data[] is simply an array, you should be able to do something like $_POST['name_of_field'][5] to get the 5th element.